# Nivo Slider Jquery Won't Slide

Tags: jquery, slider, nivo-slider

http://www.dentalbenefitprogram.com/home-new.php

I've tried fixing this for hours but my Nivo Slider won't slide.

It looks like it's loading the script--but no motion.

Loader Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
            j(document).ready(function () {
                j('#slider').nivoSlider();
            });
</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="images/Slider1.png" alt="Slider1" width="559" height="358" />
                <img src="images/slider2.png" alt="Slider1" width="559" height="358" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the version of Nivo Slider that you're using uses the deprecated .live() function. ([removed in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed))

I believe the latest version of Nivo Slider has corrected this.